# How to launch VStudio 2015 RC for ASP.NET vNext

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I installed VSStudio 2015 from here: http://www.asp.net/vnext

Installation says success but I have no icon on desktop to run why?

Comment: I'm not sure about how "Express 2015 RC for Web" differs from the actual visual studio but if I were I'd just get the Community edition from [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs.aspx) or the ISO version from [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-iso-sha1-vs.aspx)

Comment: @Nasreddine ok thanks didn't see it at first

Comment: @Nasreddine problem is that disk space is higher with vs community

Answer (score 0):

VS2015RC installation did not put an icon on my desktop either, it is in the application menu though.

The exe should be located here.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

You can create a shortcut and put it on the desktop yourself.

If you cannot find the folder maybe you need to reinstall or repair the installation.

The official download site is [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs.aspx). The community edition should have all you need to get started with ASP.NET 5 and all the vNext stuff.